# Summation by using recursive functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

i am new to python programming and i have still difficulties at some points. Now I struggle with recursive functions.
My assignment is to sum from 0 to 3 the square of that number, by using recursive functions My code so far looks like this:

```
sum = 0
n = 3
i = 1

def summe(i,sum):
    sum = sum +(i*i)
    if(i <= n):
       i = i+1
       print sum
       return summe(i, sum)
    else:
       print sum
```

The Output is empty, even the sum in the if-clause isnt printed out. I followed the examples I found online, but I dont see where i did something particular wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is empty because you never actually call the function, you just define it. Also, try to avoid naming variables native Python functions and keyword, in your case `sum` which is already a function. The way I would go about this is the following

```
def addSquares(n, stop):
    if n == stop:
        return n*n
    else:
        return n*n + addSquares(n+1, stop)  # Here is the recursion
```

For example

```
>>> addSquares(0, 3)
14
```

Comment: No, they don't need two arguments, just one.

Comment: @georg Having 2 arguments allows them to have arbitrary start and stop positions, without having to hard-code those values somewhere.

Comment: That's not the case here. The correct answer to their specific problem is `return n*n + S(n-1) if n else 0`

Comment: That answer is no more correct than the above solution, just a more specific case. The 2-argument variation is more general, and can solve the sum of squares from `A` to `B` (with `A` < `B`), instead of forcing `A` to 0.

Comment: Being defensive isn't really helpful to anyone. Your solution is confusing, and doesn't answer the question correctly. -1.

Comment: @georg I'm done arguing with you, you're nit-picking and are incorrect about your point. And my solution is indeed correct, `0*0 + 1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 ==  14`, hopefully your arithmetic isn't too rusty. And the OP accepted the solution so it did indeed solve their problem. Whether a solution is "confusing" is subjective, but saying the solution is not correct is completely untrue.

Comment: this answer is the most accurate of all and thats why I accepted it. Thanks for everybody that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You never called the function `summe`.

Answer (score 0):

Variables inside the function has a local scope , you need to initial that in the function :

```
def summe(i=1,sum=0):
```

also its better to pass n to function and use a loop inside your function !

```
    >>> def cal_sq(n):
...    return sum(cal_sq(i)+(i*i) for i in range(1,n+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would give you how recursive should be called as below. I did not understand what you want to calculate so just added n recursively you can change that to your own calculation.

```
sum = 0
n = 3
i = 1
global allsum
allsum = 0

def sum(n):
    print n
    global allsum
    allsum= allsum + n

    if n > 0:
        sum(n-1)
sum(3)
print allsum
```